# Cannot create printer object in Active Directory, even though the printer is on the same server

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, shared-printers

I'm currently setting up a new printer on my Server 2012 DC (yes I know).  I set the printer up via print management, shared it out with all the world, and then tried to add it to Active Directory.  When I add it to AD, it asks for "Network path of the pre-Windows 2000 print share (\server\share)", so I put in that information, and it returns; "A printer queue object for object \server\share cannot be created because: the parameter is incorrect"

I've never run across this before, and Google has been less than helpful, filled with "cannot add printers to XP" threads.

For kicks and giggles, I tried just mapping to the IP, but that returned the same result.

The schema is properly updated, and I'm stumped.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You used two backslashes `\\server\share`, right?

Comment: Indeed. That would have been embarrassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical strategy for publishing printers into Active Directory (AD) is to tick the box in the printer properties to "List in the directory". That will cause the Print Spooler service to publish the printer, under the machine's security context, to the AD (as a child object of the machine itself). If you want, you can move the printer object once it has been created in this manner.

I'd try the "List in the directory" box first. If it doesn't function that way you will, at least, get some Event Log messages indicating a better root cause for the failure to publish the printer (in the " Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Admin" log, logged by source "Microsoft-Windows-PrintService").

Comment: I did not know that List in the Directory meant "push to AD".  With that in mind, I was able to do a search and locate the printer, and move it to the proper OU.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know what the setting is in the Server 2012 admin tools, but in the 2008 R2 and earlier "Active Directory Users and Computers" you will need to turn on "View Users and Computers as Containers" in order to "see" the printer object nested inside the server's computer object.

Comment: Evan, I could not see the printer object on its own, I had to do a search and pull up all printers, then move it to the OU I wanted it to be in.